# Binding submit button in view to action result method in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET and MVC (I normally work in winforms/wpf) and i'm trying to teach myself the basics. I am trying to create a simple to-do list style thing where you enter a line of text into a textbox click the add button and that populates a list underneath.

Here is my view (Index.cshtml) which sits in the Views>ToDo folder:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@model List<Models.ToDoListItem>
<h2>To Do List</h2>

<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="ToDo" asp-method="post">
    <div>
        <input name="ToDoItem"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Task"/>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <ul>
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <li>
                    <label>@item.ItemText</label>
                </li>
            }
        }

    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my Controller `ToDoController.cs` which sits in the Controllers folder

```
public class ToDoController : Controller
{
    // GET: ToDo
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Models.ToDoListItem.GetAll());
    }

    [HttpPost] //This was added as suggested in comments and answers
    public ActionResult Create(string toDoItem)
    {
        Models.ToDoListItem.Create(toDoItem);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Now from what I have read, adding the action `Create`  to  the `ToDocontroller`  part to my form tag should map my submit button click to the "Create" `ActionResult` method in my `ToDoController` class.

When I run my code with a break-point on the create method, clicking the submit button doesn't hit the break-point and nothing gets added to the list.

If anyone has any idea where I went wrong, some assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Put `[HttpPost]` over `Create` method.

Comment: You are new to Asp.NET MVC and you start coding in MVC-6.. Bro try to learn from lower version first. My suggestion is start from MVC- 4..

Comment: @mmushtaq no he shouldn't. Its fine where he's starting.

Comment: Make an ajax call, that will solve your problem. :)

Comment: What @Berkay said. The default method for a form is POST, and you have no action that responds to a post. If you were to add `method="get"` to your form tag, it would work, but it should actually be a POST here, since its non-idempotent.

Comment: @Berkay unfortunately this did not work. as i said to BviLLe_Kid  i did notice an oddity with the URL where clicking the submit button directs to "localhost:62792/?ToDoItem=gjfgjf";. i would have expected more along the lines of "localhost:62792/ToDo/Create/ToDoItem=gjfgjf"; i would assume the fact it's not putting the controller or action in the url is why it's not hitting my breakpoint?

Answer (score 1):

First off, the HTML that you posted is for your `Index` view which corresponds to your `public ActionResult Index()` method.

Secondly, in order for your submit button to work, you need a `HttpPost ActionResult Create` method in your controller.  The one that you have posted is an `HttpGet ActionResult Create` method.

Something along these lines:

```
/*public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}*/

// the code above is only necessary if you decide to create your own separate Create View

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string toDoItem)
{               
    Models.ToDoListItem.Create(toDoItem);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: "you need to create a Create view" - no, he doesn't.

Comment: @Igor deleted that from my answer

Comment: neither does he need the first `Create` from your code

Comment: Then your answer boils down to the first comment under the question.

Comment: @Igor just with more visual.  The person who posted that comment could've/should've posted that as an answer, but we won't know if this is the definite solution since the OP has yet to respond to anyone

Comment: No this still doesn't work.... i did notice an oddity with the URL where clicking the submit button directs to "http://localhost:62792/?ToDoItem=gjfgjf". i would have expected more along the lines of "http://localhost:62792/ToDo/Create/ToDoItem=gjfgjf" i would assume the fact it's not putting the controller or action in the url is why it's not hitting my breakpoint?

Comment: @mattisrowe What is the default route in your `RouteConfig.cs`?

Comment: @mattisrowe the route should be `"{controller}/{action}"`

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid --> routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "ToDo", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: @mattisrowe can you declare the form to be `post` in your html?  Something like, `<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="ToDo" asp-method="post">`?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Just added this and still nothing wants to hit my create method breakpoint. however url changed to "http://localhost:62792/ToDo/Index?ToDoItem=ergerg" on the submit button click

Comment: okay so that tells me that on button click, it is still going to the Index method.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid i'm wondering if all the "asp-action="Create" asp-controller="ToDo" asp-method="post" " section requires a reference of some kind that i might be missing. That was code that i copied of some tutorial i was reading, but typing it in in VS2015 it didn't come up in my intelisense which is normally not a good sign.

Comment: @mattisrowe have you tried using the razor style for forms? [`@Html.BeginForm()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid hmm no i haven't.. i'll have a read up on it and give that a try instead.... and yes that worked... for some reason it wrote out the namespace of the mvc form as a string above the form so i just opened up the source viewer and nicked out "<form action="/ToDo/Create" method="post">" and that works perfecty! Thanks for your help :)